# Mounting a symlink

Tags: macos, keyboard, symlink, dmg

I've got a new Mac keyboard layout ready for release, I just need to package it in such a way that it can be easily installed on other machines. It's a bundle (made with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele)) and it needs to sit in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts`. I was planning on creating a .dmg with the bundle and a symlink directed to that directory, so that the bundle could be dropped in, but when the .dmg is opened the symlink appears as an inexecutable file.

I was creating the symlink using:

```
ln -s ~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts
```

Any pointers in the right direction very appreciated indeed.